# How to connect multiple dev-boards through I2C communication

Tags: pcb, circuit-design, power-electronics, i2c, pullup

Hi I am trying to build the circuitry having the devboards for the sensors like AHT21, GY521, DS3231 but the main problem is Each one of them has their own I2C Pull-up resistors if I connected them with the same I2C bus the resistors will add in parallel I want to avoid that. How can I get this issue resolved. Attached below are the links of the components I am using. Also ESP32 WROOM32 is my devboard.

https://www.aliexpress.com/item/32821951818.html?spm=a2g0o.productlist.0.0.1c145fc54ouPud&algo_pvid=188b6aff-9877-4e6b-af40-df6069e1d524&algo_exp_id=188b6aff-9877-4e6b-af40-df6069e1d524-0&pdp_ext_f=%7B%22sku_id%22%3A%2264751587499%22%7D&pdp_pi=-1%3B1.21%3B-1%3B-1%40salePrice%3BGBP%3Bsearch-mainSearch

https://www.aliexpress.com/item/4000052449080.html?spm=a2g0o.9042311.0.0.27424c4dAqapja

https://www.aliexpress.com/item/1005003707505154.html?spm=a2g0o.productlist.0.0.1a6d238e082RKK&algo_pvid=917898a9-0fbb-4955-b0b2-2b8e749e2ae9&aem_p4p_detail=202202050803441816883248468590067259392&algo_exp_id=917898a9-0fbb-4955-b0b2-2b8e749e2ae9-4&pdp_ext_f=%7B%22sku_id%22%3A%2212000026878840644%22%7D&pdp_pi=-1%3B2.41%3B-1%3B-1%40salePrice%3BGBP%3Bsearch-mainSearch

Comment: We need to see links to the actual manufacturer's datasheets...links to aliexpress are of very little value. In the absence of real datasheets you will need to unsolder some of the resistors.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to remove the pull-ups so there is only one set.

Or remove all pull-ups and put suitable on host CPU.

Or determine pull-up values and if they are suitable then just leave them in.